# Are Android support libraries necessary for high minimum SDK versions?

Tags: android

I understand that the Android support libraries provide features that do not exist yet in low Android API levels, for example Fragment.

But then, does it also mean that, for example, if I specify the minimum SDK version of my app to be 14, then I have no need for the v4, v7, v8 and v13 support libraries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ViewPager` which is a commonly used class is only available in the support libraries. There are other classes that are also only available in the support libraries. Some classes like Fragments are included in the support library for backwards compatibility. So it depends on what you need.